# What is this giant 50cm flower?

Tags: identification, flowers, tropical

I found this in a garden in the French Alps at 275m high, any ideas what it is? The red bit is about 40cm and the green is about 50cm.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Dracunculus vulgaris, commonly known as Voodoo lily, snake lily, stink lily and other names. It's a deciduous, tuberous plant, which, despite its exotic appearance, grows well in temperate climes. Further information here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/bulbs/dragon-arum-lily/growing-dragon-arums.htm